# Could not load C:\Windows\TEMP\Sybase.AdoNet4.AseClient.32bits.4.157.501.0\sbgse2.dll

Tags: c#, .net, sap-ase

I am running into a problem using the Sybase drivers.  I get the following when Sybase tries to create a connection.

```
[AseException: Could not load C:\Windows\TEMP\Sybase.AdoNet4.AseClient.32bits.4.157.501.0\sbgse2.dll]
   Sybase.Data.AseClient1.AseConnection.SaveAndLoadLibrary(String dirName, String dllName, Int32 bits) +419
   Sybase.Data.AseClient1.AseConnection.LoadLibraries() +243
   Sybase.Data.AseClient1.AseConnection..cctor() +5

[TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Sybase.Data.AseClient1.AseConnection' threw an exception.]
   Sybase.Data.AseClient1.AseConnection..ctor(AseConnection realConnection) +0
   Sybase.Data.AseClient.AseConnection..ctor() +27
```

I see that Sybase compiles some unmanaged code as embedded resources and then at runtime if these files are not in the temp directory it copies them there.

In my case I see that the files do in fact exist.  I can even delete them and see them get copied back at runtime.

I'm stumped now as to why they cannot be loaded.

This machine at one time was running .net 4.5. It was uninstalled and the .net 4.0 re-installed. Not sure that has anything to do with it.

Here is the relevant code in the Sybase driver

```
    private static void LoadLibraries()
   {
     int bits = IntPtr.Size * 8;
     string str = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(),    Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name + "." + bits.ToString() + "bits." +    ((object) Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version).ToString());
     if (!Directory.Exists(str))
       Directory.CreateDirectory(str);
       Sybase.Data.AseClient1.AseConnection.SaveAndLoadLibrary(str, "sbgse2.dll",   bits);
     Sybase.Data.AseClient1.AseConnection.SaveAndLoadLibrary(str, "sybdrvado20.dll", bits);
   }

   private static void SaveAndLoadLibrary(string dirName, string dllName, int bits)
   {
     string str = Path.Combine(dirName, dllName);
     if (!File.Exists(str))
     {
       using (Stream manifestResourceStream =    Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("Sybase.Data.AseClient.Resources._" + bits.ToString() + "bits." + dllName))
       {
         try
         {
           using (Stream stream = (Stream) File.Create(str))
           {
             byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
             while (true)
             {
               int count = manifestResourceStream.Read(buffer, 0, 4096);
               if (count >= 1)
                 stream.Write(buffer, 0, count);
               else
                 break;
             }
             stream.Close();
           }
         }
         catch
         {
         }
       }
     }
     if (Sybase.Data.AseClient1.AseConnection.LoadLibrary(str) == IntPtr.Zero)
       throw new AseException("Could not load " + str);
  }

   [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
   public static IntPtr LoadLibrary(string dllToLoad);
```

Any thoughts or ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears (for some reason) the files copied to c:\windows\temp took on special permissions from the AppPool where this codes was initialized, causing other app pools to not be able to read the file.  For this I would have expected an Access Denied type exception.

It's still a bit of magic and hand waving at best, but removing the special perms of the app pool from the files, deleting the temp directory, and restarting has kept the erroring application (in a different app pool) from throwing this exception. The special permissions also have not reappeared on the temp files.

Comment: Deleting the sybase folders created in the c:\windows\temp worked. Automatically those will be created again. I have parallel wcf and web service. Now i tested web service first so sybase folder created with IIS permission. Now both working fine in parallel. No issues

Answer (score 0):

Since all application pools identities have to be in the IIS worker process group, a solution is to grant ***Modify*** permissions to the **C:\Windows\TEMP** folder for the IIS group :

- **IIS_WPG** for ***IIS 6***
- **IIS_IUSRS** for ***IIS 7***

The rights will be correctly inherited (verified on a Windows Server 2008 and IIS 7).

Answer (score 0):

What finally worked for me was assigning the application pools to the same identity.

1. Stop both applications pools
2. Delete directory "Windows\temp\Sybase.AdoNet4.AseClient.32bits.4.157.1000.0
3. Assign identity NETWORK SERVICE to both application pools
4. Start both application pools.
5. Everything should work.
6. Do Steps 1 and 2.
7. Created Custom Identity by going to "Control Panel > Administrative Tools > Computer Management > Local Users and Groups > Users"
8. Right click and select "New User..."
9. Add new username and password
10. Click Create button and close dialog
11. In IIS, select first Application Pool > Advanced Settings
12. Click on Identity field > click ... button
13. Select Custom account, click Set... button
14. Enter new user account information, click OK
15. Click OK to close Application Pool Identity dialog
16. Click OK to close Advanced Settings.
17. Repeat steps 11-16 for second Application Pool
18. Do step 4.

Final note, in the web.config you may need to specify multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" in the tag serviceHostingEnvironment in the section system.serviceModel.

Comment: I guess I should added this was on Windows Server 2012 and IIS 8.5

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the identity on your AppPool from ApplicationPoolIdentity to LocalSystem.